# What is this natural trumpet?

Tags: instruments, brass, baroque-period, trumpet

In this picture of the *London Gabrieli Brass Ensemble* found [here](https://www.discogs.com/artist/1836983-The-London-Gabrieli-Brass-Ensemble), one sees what I suppose are natural brass instruments.

[image: Five musicians with brass instruments. The musician in the lower right corner is holding a curved trumpet-like instrument.]

Does the trumpet in the lower right corner have a specific name? It has a different form than the baroque trumpet that looks like this (from [this site](https://sites.google.com/site/windstumusic/home/natural-trumpet)):

[image: A baroque natural trumpet - consisting of a single loop, but otherwise long and straight.]

Comment: If it's helpful, that trumpeter is David Blackadder, principal trumpet of the Orchestra of the Age of Enlightenment.

Comment: Blackadder?   He must have a cunning plan

Comment: He played at the wedding of Prince Harry and Meghan Markle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a demilune trumpet. There are lots of images on google.

[image]

Item 72 from the Natural Trumpets catalogue of the Bate Musical Instrument collection.

> Demilune trumpet  c.1840 This trumpet is made of brass. It has a
>   central tuning slide. It is also curved probably to make hand stopping
>   easier. It was made by Dubois & Cie.

If you look carefully you'll see Prof. Blackadder's trumpet has an extra loop just after the mouthpiece, so this picture isn't the same instrument he's playing.

Comment: Demilune - half moon. Apposite naming!

Comment: The "extra loop" is a crook that the player will remove to change the key of the instrument. See https://collections.ed.ac.uk/stcecilias/record/96059